# How to pass different argument to gdbus like unit16, uint32

Tags: dbus

By default arguments sent to gdbus are taken to be of type Int32.
I need to send arguments of mixed type like uint16, uint32 ..
How to frame the arguments for gdbus for same
Unfortunately there are not many examples of such usecases in the net.
I am trying to frame the gdbus emit signal with above type of arguments.

Below is example of what I am trying

```
gdbus emit -y -o /myservice/serverInstance -s com.mimo.myservice.touch "(2,1)"
```

Below is the output

```
signal sender=:1.5 -> dest=(null destination) serial=6606 path=/myservice/serverInstance; interface=com.mimo.myservice; member=touch
       struct {
          int32 2
          int32 1
       }
```

In above case, I need to send second argument as uint16.
Hot to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below command works 
Arguments should follow GVariant standard : 
https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/gvariant-text.html

```
gdbus emit -y -o /myservice/serverInstance -s com.mimo.myservice.touch "(2, unit16 1)"
```